# Pytorch passing PackSequence argument to LSTM

Tags: lstm, pytorch

As per my understanding, `pack_sequence` and `pack_padded_sequence` returns a `PackedSequence`, for which its `data` attribute should always be 1 dimension.

However, the following code gives the error:
`RuntimeError: input must have 2 dimensions, got 1`.

```
import torch
import torch.nn.utils.rnn as rnn_utils
a = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3])
b = torch.Tensor([4, 5])
c = torch.Tensor([6])
seq = rnn_utils.pack_sequence([a, b, c])
lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(
    input_size=3,
    hidden_size=3
)
lstm(seq)
```

I've tried `batch_first=True`, that did not work.

The source file of error code: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py#L127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

1. Input size should be 1
2. LSTM takes a vector at each time step, you are passing scalars and hence the dimension error.

Below code should fix the problem. I made each input a (1,) size array and changed input size to 1.

```
import torch 
import torch.nn.utils.rnn as rnn_utils 
a = torch.Tensor([[1], [2], [3]]) 
b = torch.Tensor([[4], [5]]) 
c = torch.Tensor([[6]]) 
seq = rnn_utils.pack_sequence([a, b, c]) 
lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size=1, hidden_size=3) 
lstm(seq)
```

The packed sequence can be multi-dimensional and it depends on the data at each time step. For example in this case `seq` will be

```
PackedSequence(data=tensor([[1.],
        [4.],
        [6.],
        [2.],
        [5.],
        [3.]]), batch_sizes=tensor([3, 2, 1]))
```